# Map not displaying on site

Tags: jquery, html, google-maps-api-3

Hi I'm working on adding a a Google map to this page http://talentfo.axiscms.net/locations

I'm using the gmaps.js script from http://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/

But as you can see the map doesn't show—just the container for it. I've been racking my brains on this one and I would really appreciate some help—thanks!

Comment: Not sure what browser you are using but look into Chrome Dev Tools or something like that for whatever your browser is. Small errors are easier to spot when you use this stuff.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors on the page (you can view this from Console in Google Chrome by pressing F12):

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of null @ scrollfixed.js:4
>
> Uncaught ReferenceError: prettyPrint is not defined @ locations:141

If you remove the prettyPrint() from line 141 (or fix the reference), the map will show up.

Answer (score 0):

If you browse to your URL you can see you have errors. A function is not defined on your page.

See Image

[image]